# DDEV doesn't handle SVGZ-files in Nginx

Tags: nginx, svg, ddev

I use DDEV v1.15.3 with Typo3 v9 environment. I created the Typo3 environment according to the Quick Guide with **ddev config --project-type=typo3 --php-version 7.3 --docroot=public --create-docroot=true**. So far everything works fine, but no SVGZ files are displayed.

A svgz file uploaded in the backend in the fileadmin is not displayed in the browser - like https://ddev-typo3v9.ddev.site:444/fileadmin/user_upload/meinen_jmd_vor_ort_finden.svgz. I get the following error message:

***This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 1: Encoding error
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.***

To enable compression with gzip in the nginx-container, I added the following lines to the file **.ddev/nginx_full/nginx-site.conf**

```
# Compression
gzip on;
gzip_proxied        any;
gzip_comp_level     6; # Level of compression
gzip_http_version   1.1;
gzip_min_length     1100;
gzip_buffers        16 8k;

gzip_types
 text/plain
 text/css
 text/xml
 application/x-javascript
 application/atom+xml
 text/mathml
 text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor
 text/vnd.wap.wml
 text/x-component
 text/javascript
 application/javascript
 application/json
 application/xml
 application/rss+xml
 font/truetype
 font/opentype
 application/vnd.ms-fontobject
 image/svg+xml svg svgz;

gzip_static on;
gunzip on;
gzip_proxied        expired no-cache no-store private auth;
gzip_disable        "MSIE [1-6] \."; # Disable for IE < 6

# Add a vary header for downstream proxies to avoid sending
# cached gzipped files to IE6
gzip_vary on;

# ### Compression ###

# For CSS with compression
location ~* "\.css(\.|\.\d{10}\.)gzip$" {
        rewrite ^(.+css)\.(\d+\.)gzip$ /$1.gzip;
        add_header  Content-Encoding gzip;
        add_header  Vary Accept-Encoding;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        gzip off;
        types { text/css gzip; }
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
}

# For JavaScript with compression
location ~* "\.js(\.|\.\d{10}\.)gzip$" {
        rewrite ^(.+js)\.(\d+\.)gzip$ /$1.gzip;
        add_header  Content-Encoding gzip;
        add_header  Vary Accept-Encoding;
        gzip off;
        default_type application/javascript;
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
}

# Compression for SVGZ
location ~* \.svgz$ {
       add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
}
```

When I use **ddev ssh** to connect to the docker container, the nginx configuration also contains the above lines.

Thanks for your help.

Best greetings

-- Gerald

Comment: I initially completely missed the point, but now added an answer that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

What you need in .ddev/nginx_full/nginx-site.conf is adding

```
location ~ \.svgz$ { add_header Content-Encoding gzip; }
```

I put my nginx-site.conf file at https://gist.github.com/rfay/5071ff19237ee7b83442cd8ad0311459

I used the file [example.svgz](https://example-files.online-convert.com/vector%20image/svgz/example.svgz) from https://www.online-convert.com/file-format/svgz

[This nginx issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/372) explained what to do.

Here's what I see after 1) Uploading example.svgz with the file manager and then 2) Clicking the "show" icon.

[image]

If you think this is important to add to the default nginx configurations, please open an issue or a PR at https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues